# How to access class within class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

My question is how do you access "A_Numer", "A_String", "A_Property" from Class1.
(Whatever I try typing in Class1 I get 'type does not exist in current context' Which is funny, because everything is public.)  Thank You!

```
public class Class1
{        


    public class Class2
    {               
        public int A_Number = 0;

        public string A_String(int fdsa)
        {
            return "dssdaff";
        }

        public string A_Property { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Class1 doesn't have anything except Class2.

Comment: What did you actually try in terms of accessing Class1 & Class2?

Comment: Why do you want a nested public class?  Doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel their is nothing wrong with accessing the `Class2` instances from `Class1`, I hope that you may Directly Defined the instance and tried to access properties, Something like this:

```
 public class Class1
 {
     Class2 Class2Instance = new Class2();
     Class2Instance.A_Number = 11;     // not possible     

     public class Class2
     {
        // definition here
     }
 }
```

But if you Access them through a method or constructor, everything will be fine and works perfect, See this:

```
public class Class1
{
    // Constructor
    public Class1()
    {
        Class2 Class2Instance = new Class2();
        Class2Instance.A_Number=11;
    }

    class Class2
    {
        public int A_Number = 0;

        public string A_String(int fdsa)
        {
            return "dssdaff";
        }

        public string A_Property { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Note :** In this case their is no need for the inner class to be public

Comment: Ah, I tried to put "Class1.Class2 Experiment = new Class1.Class2();
        Experiment.A_Number=0" directly in. Not in a method... ;-/ Thank You! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need this but here is how you can do this

```
Class1.Class2 obj = new Class1.Class2();
obj.A_Number = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to create object for class2

```
Class1.Class2 Object_Name=new Class1.Class2();
```